# Delete slightly repeating items from list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list. It's Random. I would like to delete items from the list whenever they're repeated.

I would only want these urls(items) in my list.

```
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13ohzibgwq3yjw4u04cglzhxmioy5phrn00k
```

I would only delete these urls(items) from my list.

```
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13ohzibgwq3yjw4u04cglzhxmioy5phrn00k.1479303517063659
```

`urlList` is the variable which holds it all.

```
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12ntbeg5nvptj2pv04chz5roqfpyxpp1to0k
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13ohzibgwq3yjw4u04cglzhxmioy5phrn00k
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13ohzibgwq3yjw4u04cglzhxmioy5phrn00k.1479303517063659
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12zt3fagtymh3nta23dhpsohmjocfwqd04
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12mv3rgatfcf3jvq22tuzgzcmfadbtvi
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13ohrfy3mb5xphyh04cd3shfq2bzhr5up00k
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13ohrfy3mb5xphyh04cd3shfq2bzhr5up00k.1475086029972480
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13ohrfy3mb5xphyh04cd3shfq2bzhr5up00k.1475086070389366
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13qulw4jvafgxo1322hdfnitwv5u35d0
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13qulw4jvafgxo1322hdfnitwv5u35d0.1478197028336117
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12xxv3r3py3jv5en23vjft4gxb3jhnkx
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12xxv3r3py3jv5en23vjft4gxb3jhnkx.1478703511076217
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12fzxwqwlr4xdkao04cflhbawivd1gq2jc
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12oczcbksudef3cq23psfd4cqjycro5e04
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12oczcbksudef3cq23psfd4cqjycro5e04.1478790261949273
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z135h1sxqprthvfdl23hsh2qdrmggpzsc
```

What I want:

```
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12ntbeg5nvptj2pv04chz5roqfpyxpp1to0k
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13ohzibgwq3yjw4u04cglzhxmioy5phrn00k
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12zt3fagtymh3nta23dhpsohmjocfwqd04
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12mv3rgatfcf3jvq22tuzgzcmfadbtvi
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13ohrfy3mb5xphyh04cd3shfq2bzhr5up00k
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z13qulw4jvafgxo1322hdfnitwv5u35d0
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12xxv3r3py3jv5en23vjft4gxb3jhnkx
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12fzxwqwlr4xdkao04cflhbawivd1gq2jc
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z12oczcbksudef3cq23psfd4cqjycro5e04
/watch?v=iOpJywrdCuQ&lc=z135h1sxqprthvfdl23hsh2qdrmggpzsc
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Discard the string from `.` on, and then put it in a set.

Answer (score 0):

Test for matching regex for the character `.` (represented by `\.` since `.` is reserved for `any char`):

```
import re
without_dot = []
for x in open('file.txt').read().split('\n'):
    if not re.match('\.', x):
        without_dot.append(x)
```

Comment: re.match() is valid for matching at the beginning of a string.  Use re.search() in this case.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to delete items from a list without writing python code is to use `grep -v` which outputs all lines that *do not* match a pattern.

```
grep -v "\.[0-9][0-9]*$" input.txt > output.txt
```

Or we can use enhanced regex if we use egrep (I'm on a MAC):

```
egrep -v "\.\d+$" input.txt > output.txt
```

Above, I used the regex ".\d+$" to match any line ending ($) with a period followed by 1 or more numbers (\d+).

Here's a python equivalent:

```
import re
with open('input.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    if not re.search(r'\.\d+$',line):
      print(line,end='')
```